# displaying json string keys with their values as input feild

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json

I'm trying to diplay a json that is in this format :

> {
> "color" : ['black','white','yellow'],
> "storage" : ['128','256','500','1000'],
> "brand" : ['apple' , 'samsung'],
> }

note that the keys here can be different every time it is not static.
however, I want the values of each key to be enters by the user.

I want it to look something like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysupV.png)

this is the code i have so far.

```
{rs.map(([key, value]) => (
<div key={key}>
<label htmlFor={key}>{key}</label>
<input
      type="text"
      id={key}
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(key, e.target.value)}
    />
</div>
))}
```

but this code is displaying this to me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOrmX.png)

how do I fix this? please explain the solution you would provide I'm a beginner

Comment: Welcome. The use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate through keys so you can do like below

```html
<div>
    {
    Object.keys(rs).map((key) => (
        <div key={key}>
            <label htmlFor={key}>{key}</label>
            {
                rs[key].map((value, index) => (
                  <input
                      type="text"
                      id={value}
                      value={value}
                      onChange={(e)=>handleInputChange(key, index, e.target.value)}
                  />
            ))}
        </div>
    ))}
  </div>
```